# Node.JS and Express: get application host without request

Tags: node.js, express

I have running Node.JS & Express application on localhost (127.0.0.1) and I need to find out the current host (domain) without making requests (for cron job that starts when server is created). The server is created this way

```
   app = express.createServer();
   app.listen(PORT);
```

Now I've found following solution

```
   app.address();
```

However the host returned by this is `0.0.0.0`, port is returned correct so I guess I need to somehow specify the host during the server start. How can I force it to get the correct host? I've tried

```
  app = express.createServer({host: '127.0.0.1'});
```

but that doesn't work :(

Comment: The reason you can't get a host before a request is that you can't really know it without one.  Your host can be changed by a reverse proxy such as Nginx.  Since node very often sits behind these reverse proxies in production environments, it would be a very inaccurate function, therefore it is not there.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am running a `cron` using `node-cron` module, which exports a csv and mails the link to requester's email id. But I am not able to create a link that will work based on the environment. I do not want to hardcode it.

Answer (score 3):

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/os.html#os.hostname

> os.hostname()
>
> Returns the hostname of the operating system.

Looks like it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I've meant. I'm trying to get host (domain name) like www.foobar.com or IP address (for example 127.0.0.1 for localhost)

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but yours suggestion returns the same as `uname -n` in linux (or computer name in Windows). But the application is running on localhost (127.0.0.1) so I want to get 127.0.0.1

Comment: @ladar: Uhm... you want your IPs, not your hostname?

Answer (score 0):

You cant. You have to make a request to something like http://whatismyip.org/

But the reason you want it for can be changed. There are some modules that can be used instead of an actual cron job to do what you want.

https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: I'm actually using this module but the function it triggers needs to know the host name to work properly. I'm kind of confused, why is there the `app.address()` if you can't get the host?

Answer (score 0):

Host may be reached by more than one Ip, you can find good example how to get it - at following article [Get local IP address in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but anyone landing here looking for help, try this:

```
app.get('ip')
```

you can get same way port

```
app.get('port')
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me