# Return machine IP address using nodejs exec on windows command line

Tags: node.js, exec, command-line-interface, ping

I'm attempting to return the IP address of the Windows machine into a node process using child.exec.  Simple command lines seem to work but anything vaguely complex fails - anyone got any suggested resolutions / explanations for why it's failing?

Code as follows:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var ifconfig = (process.platform !== undefined && process.platform !== 'win32') ? 'ifconfig eth0' : 'ping -4 %COMPUTERNAME%';

var child = exec(ifconfig, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log('child', stdout);
});
```

var 
FYI 'ping %COMPUTERNAME%' works, 'ping %COMPUTERNAME% -4'fails.

Also FYI, original suggestion for CLI code from here:

http://ayesamson.com/2011/06/13/get-ip-address-from-windows-command-line/

Ta

N

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using [os.networkInterfaces](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750303/how-can-i-get-the-local-ip-address-in-node-js

Comment: Nope - simply didn't know about it - I knew some bright spark would suggest an alternative ;-)  Having said that, I would still like to know why the code is failing for future reference.

Comment: Your code worked fine on my machine. Using Windows 8 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks user - very interesting - I'm running Win7 X64.  I don't suppose you have Powershell installed do you (I don't)?