# Get LAN IP of connected user in my node.js app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

How would I get the LAN IP of a user connected to my node.js app ?
I can get the WAN IP, but not sure how to get the LAN IP. I tried this

[How can I get the local IP address in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750303/how-can-i-get-the-local-ip-address-in-node-js)

but all it does is give the LAN IP of the machine the node app is running on.

Comment: of what use could the user's local IP be to you? if they're behind a nat gateway, they're almost guaranteed to be in one of the 3 private IP blocks anyways.

Comment: You can't... at least not directly.  And, this question has been asked at least 100 times on Stack Overflow.