# How to get my system local ip using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I need to get local IP of my computer in react js app. Can anyone please suggest a good way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? You've tagged electron, so maybe an approach that works with Electron is what you need, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750303/how-can-i-get-the-local-ip-address-in-node-js

Comment: Local LAN IP? Or public internet-facing IP, if any? IPv4? IPv6? What if your device has more than one active network interface, should it return all the assigned IPs? And yeah...why does your application need to know?

Comment: @AKX he's asking how we can get unique address of a device (i.e. IPv4) using React.js, not Node.js, because if you follow the approach suggested in the article is to do it on Node.js (Server side), so it'll record the IP of the server not the client.

Comment: @AkashRajawat I believe with electron you can use node modules on the client side

Comment: @AkashRajawat As I said, they'd tagged Electron, where Node.js code runs on the client side. If you look at the accepted answer, that's exactly what they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any IP address of your machine you can find by using the `os` module - and that's native to Node.js:

```
const os = require('os');

const networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
const ip = networkInterfaces['eth0'][0]['address']

console.log(networkInterfaces);
```

**Update: Window OS solution**

```
const { networkInterfaces } = require('os');

const getIPAddress = () => {
  const nets = networkInterfaces();
  const results = {};

  for (const name of Object.keys(nets)) {
    for (const net of nets[name]) {
      // Retrieve only IPv4 addresses
      if (net.family === 'IPv4' && !net.internal) {
        if (!results[name]) {
          results[name] = [];
        }
        results[name].push(net.address);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Return the first IP address for the first NIC found
  const nicNames = Object.keys(results);
  if (nicNames.length > 0) {
    const firstNICAddresses = results[nicNames[0]];
    if (firstNICAddresses.length > 0) {
      return firstNICAddresses[0];
    }
  }
  
  // No IP address found
  return null;
};

const ipAddress = getIPAddress();
console.log(ipAddress);
```

This solution retrieves all network interfaces and their associated IP addresses using the os.networkInterfaces() method. It then filters out all IPv4 addresses that are internal (e.g., loopback) and stores them in an object indexed by NIC names.

Finally, the code returns the first IP address found for the first NIC in the object, or null if no IP address was found.

Comment: I had to run `npm i --save os` to get it to work.

Comment: What about on Windows? eth0 isn't Windows

Comment: @velkoon, I have updated my code with Window OS solution. Upvote if it's usefull for you. :)

Comment: @MahmoudMousaHamad I guess you don't need to install it. It's native to NodeJS, see https://nodejs.org/api/os.html

Comment: it says: Uncaught TypeError: os.networkInterfaces is not a function
and does not work for me

Comment: But if the backend code (Node.js server) is deployed on a server, and developer's intention is to get IP addresses of it's user, how this would help? I think this will only provide IP of the server.

Answer (score -2):

windows.location.host to get the ip address and port

if you want just to get the ip address
const address = window.location.host.split(':')[0]

if you want to change the port
const address = window.location.host.split(':')[0] + ':3001'

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/host - it gets you the host name of the URL of the current page the browser is on. That is nothing to do with the local IP, and it is often a hostname rather than an IP address anyway. This answer is entirely incorrect, unfortunately

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).