# check is nodejs connection come from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to check where the nodejs connection come from?

in javascript we do

```
if (window.location.host == "localhost")
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

however I have no idea how to do it in nodejs, I want to do ( then I'll only need to maintain 1 folder for the git repo )

```
if (window.location.host == "localhost"){
    // connect to localhost mongodb
}else{
    // connect to mongodb uri
}
```

Comment: You could check the [request IP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8107856/575527) against the [server's IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js)

Comment: End up using the `require("os")` method, helpful comment

Answer (score 6):

```
var os = require('os');
var database_uri;

if(os.hostname().indexOf("local") > -1)
  database_uri = "mongodb://localhost/database";
else
  database_uri = "mongodb://remotehost/database";

//Connect to database
mongoose.connect(database_uri, 
                 function(err){
                   if(err) console.log(err); 
                   else console.log('success');});
```

Comment: If you change your hostname (give your computer a name), this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is by using:

`req.connection.remoteAddress`

Comment: `req.connection.remoteAddress` is deprecated, use `req.socket.remoteAddress`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the ip V4 in express like this:

```js
let ipV4 = req.connection.remoteAddress.replace(/^.*:/, '');
if (ipV4 === '1') ipV4 = 'localhost';
```

ipV4 contains the proper value of the calling client, being === 'localhost' if it'S accessing the machine via that way.

You must understand that it works different like for a js script running in a browser, this is about a client connecting to the server via a network interface.

For your described use-case, i.e. accessing via 'localhost' this will do.

For other use-case you might need to do more than that, but **local** means it is using one of the interfaces from the machine, so you could check all of them for a match.

Answer (score 1):

Check `req.headers.host`. If it is localhost or 127.0.0.1 use your logic to do localhost stuff.
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage

`req.headers.host` also contains the port, which you might have to clip before checking.

Comment: That is rather dangerous, since anyone can spoof headers.