# Can't connect to Node web-server hosted on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

I'm running a node app on an Amazon EC2. The app includes a simple web server intended to serve the index page, but it doesn't work.

Here's the server code:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
io = require('socket.io'),
index;

fs.readFile('client.html', function(err, data){
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    index = data;
});

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHeader(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(index);
    response.end();
}).listen(1223);
```

The EC2 is assigned the public IP address `54.187.31.42`. I run the app, open my browser, connect to `54.187.31.42:1223` expecting to be served a web page and get nothing.

1. What is wrong with my server code?
2. I used the snippet found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js) to check the IP of the EC2 running the app, and oddly get `172.31.3.67` - why is the returned address different from the one assigned to the machine by Amazon?

Consequently, trying to connect to `172.31.3.67:1223` also fails.

---

Straight from the Amazon dev controls, if that helps confirm it isn't an issue of the server IP being wrong or something.

[image]

Comment: Is there an error message in your terminal or the page?

Comment: No, there's no indication of a connection attempt in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks fine, try connecting with the public IP/public DNS that you see in the AWS console.

Try the following and your application would work:

1. Open the port (in your case 1223) in the security groups of your instance.
2. stop the firewall on your machine (i.e. iptables) and now access your server using public ip or public DNS.

If you can now acceess your machine that means something in the iptables is filtering your traffic. You can modify the iptables rules accordingly.

Comment: Exactly the problem! I changed the security group to allow everything on all ports and it works now. Thank you. Now, what problems do I create for myself by allowing everything, rather than being specific in the security groups? Is this something that I should pay attention to, study, and later configure properly?

Comment: hey you do not need to allow everything on all the ports. Just open the port on which your application is accepting connections and in your case its 1223, right?

Comment: Well, there were so many different types of connections to allow ports on, it was the first method that worked. Of course, I plan to learn what the different connection types mean and configure accordingly, hence the question in my comment

Comment: Allow "Custom tcp" traffic on port number 1223, thats all. It should work then also.

Answer (score 2):

In security group, add a rule with the type "Custom TCP Rule" on the used port (e.g. port: 3000 or 1223 for this case). It works for me.