# Azure Database Firewall Issue

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

when we have a web apps, should we set our web apps IP in the Azure Database Firewall rule ? because i have some problem with the connection between my Azure web apps and my Azure database, and i am curious is it because the database firewall rule .

Thanks .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266884/configure-azure-sql-database-firewall-for-just-my-web-app

Answer (score 2):

No, just set the checkbox in the firewall that allows access to Azure services.

Answer (score 0):

To allow Azure applications to connect to Azure SQL server, Azure connections need to be enabled, which will allow Azure-hosted services through the firewall. Besides, you could allow Outbound IP Addresses of the Azure Web App in SQL Azure using a specific firewall rule. For more information, please refer to [this article](https://blog.josequinto.com/2016/09/19/enable-sql-azure-access-from-azure-webjobs-by-adding-firewall-rules-using-powershell/).

Comment: there are 4 outbound IP in azure, should i add 4 of them to firewall rule ?

Comment: You should post the main contents in a quote in here, the link could be inactive in the future.

Comment: ``there are 4 outbound IP in azure, should i add 4 of them to firewall rule ?`` yes, 4 outbound IPs should be added to firewall rule.