# package.json - how to get IP address of local machine?

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have a node.js application that uses webpack-dev-server, so in my package.json I have this to start it:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 192.168.0.13 --port 3001",
}
...
```

`192.168.0.13` is my local IP address. As my network uses DHCP, is there a variable that I can use instead of my IP address in package.json or webpack.config.js file, so that it will always use my local IP?

Note: I have read that I can use `0.0.0.0`, but this is apparently insecure, so is there something else I can use directly in my package.json or webpack.config.js file that will dynamically provide `webpack-dev-server` with my local IP address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get local IP address in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js)

Comment: Not really, this above question is directly in node, whereas my question is in package.json itself.

Comment: you can modify the json file using a simple code in nodejs.

Comment: You want to post an answer for that?

Comment: @OmG do you want to remove that 'duplicate' notification at the top of this question or proved an answer!?

Comment: json file modification can be done in different ways. You can use this package as an example. https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file

Comment: And how do you specifically use this with webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the host can be dynamically set within `webpack.config.js` using the `host` option:

```
...
devServer: {
    host: require('os').hostname().toLowerCase(),
    port: 3001,
    ...
},
...
```

Comment: This does not really answer the original question, as it is depending on webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your IP address inside of package.json with the `ipconfig getifaddr en0` command like this:

`"start": "webpack-dev-server --host \"$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)\" --port 3001"`