# How can i display the ip address exposing an express.js development server to other machines in the network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, ip-address

When I start up a basic `express.js` server I usually `console.log` a message that says it is running and listening on port .

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('App reached.'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

However, I would like to add to this message the available IP address exposing the app to other machines on the network. Somewhat like create-react-app basic template does. How can i reach that info with my `javascript` code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get local IP address in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has indeed already been answered:
[Get local IP address in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js)

I preferred this solution:

```
npm install ip
```

```
const express = require('express');
const ip = require('ip');
const ipAddress = ip.address();
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('App reached.'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
  console.log(`Network access via: ${ipAddress}:${port}!`);
});
```