# Get ip and port from server node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make a web page for my node js project. Currently I have

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const httpserver = http.Server(app);
const gamedirectory = path.join(__dirname, "public");
app.use(express.static(gamedirectory));
httpserver.listen(3000);
```

But I don't have the ip and port of my project. How do I get these with node js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get local IP address in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```js
let ip = require("ip");
console.log( ip.address() );
```

This question is already answered [Get local IP address in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js)