# How to deal with multiple possible return types in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have looked into this thread [Get local IP address in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653065/get-local-ip-address-in-node-js), where I want to implement a piece of code:

```js
import net from 'net';

const getNetworkIP = (callback: any) => {
  var socket = net.createConnection(80, 'www.google.com');
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    const sa = socket.address();
    callback(undefined, sa.address);
    socket.end();
  });
  socket.on('error', function (e) {
    callback(e, 'error');
  });
};
```

I can not call `sa.address` because the `socket.address()` will return either `{}` or `net.AddressInfo`. How to deal with this common code scenario in typescript? How can I access the `address` attribute safely?

Answer (score 3):

This is weird since [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#socketaddress) don't mention the possibility of returning an empty object.

However, blaming the `@types/node` declaration files leads to [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/48780) with [the comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/48780#discussion_r504642661)

> ```
> -    address(): AddressInfo;
> +    address(): AddressInfo | {};
> ```
>
> In case of windows pipes or unix domain sockets `{}` is returned (server returns the path as string).

So if you're certain that this doesn't apply to your code, you can use a type assertion:

```
const sa = socket.address() as net.AddressInfo;
callback(undefined, sa.address);
```

but if you want to do it properly and detect the occurrence you'd write

```
const sa = socket.address();
if ('address' in sa) {
  callback(undefined, sa.address);
} else {
  callback(new Error(`Expected an AddressInfo object, got ${sa}`));
}
```

Comment: interesting that the typescript compiler is so intelligent that he now allows sa.address now just because the programmer checked if this attribute is in sa. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the shape of the returned value at runtime with a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). See comments below:

> Ref: [Class: `net.Socket` | Net | Node.js v18.12.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/net.html#class-netsocket)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgDsUYAaOGATzBTgEEkkoUCCBJYtCSmuuAGUIAYwDWZAL5w0UCCDgByYhFQAuUjEUBuAFC6A9AbgAVABb1+9CGjjUIWKHBEYcOAEYZxcAsADmxBgwjvQ4EBBiRDjAEnDAWkQQpHA2VBYEKGq6VnAAcmQA7tBiHAAKAMKuHl5icAC8iLpwcAYAVK1wAGLQcGYYxEjRxH5w-XAoUHJOrQZNcAAUE1NqcACik9CUIAR+K4pL0IoAlCsAbhDASHrNbR3dTn0DQyMYcEjABCIQpxMoSKPMVjsOAzObzAD6BygKywA3QwFISEoGEBbAIKwIMCgCL8Jzg50uekkekM7VMtHofiwGCg-zQsJEMGASRBs3pxEZzOIcQITBYaK4PAWCJ4KwASmRHMQTBSADzCcRkADaihR-PYigAugA+PEiiA8xio9iCg0IOasYJQbnzObNKypfX1OoNRQQdwAKxQjMUdrgADJ-VQKal5k7CEb1ZxuBAjgB+AB0aqBRBdrsx2OGvuazUDwboofDRD5KdN8YTmBAwBw1Gd6axOOzObzDtsYZjo2LxujPHLkFgdaUxCwIHcEybRyJ+i+xExcD8ZHyMCKUBKpXqCxcbk84hWS5Xa8q25qR3q2sazRnc4Iogk8AamgTIlYQRQ5SSpE5SXmAA4AAyUIoBTAQmfjhH4OAoE+8jHCSzQ3oqMAJt+igzp+WiUPMp51Oe5o5s4SRzk6DQIXeSbdlhcE5sAbYfCWAoxu2vanlu1TiPMsKoGgCJ-JQ+rkVGk5+igOAZM4VQ7mI8ykAUawbFA8yKAqd4AlGJAQPAPCcccgFQrB+j4aRZAJigAyUXMkhCXMRlIShemYVC2HnqxkmLPJunyccQnEroQA)

```ts
import {default as net, type AddressInfo, type Socket} from 'node:net';

// The type of your callback signature looks like it's one of these:
type NetworkIPCallback = {
  /** For handling an error */
  (error: Error, msg: 'error'): void;
  /** For handling a discovered address */
  (_error: undefined, address: string): void;
};

/** Type guard function */
function isAddressInfo (info: ReturnType<Socket['address']>): info is AddressInfo {
  return (
    typeof info === 'object'
    && typeof (info as AddressInfo)?.address === 'string'
    && typeof (info as AddressInfo)?.family === 'string'
    && typeof (info as AddressInfo)?.port === 'number'
  );
}

const getNetworkIP = (callback: NetworkIPCallback) => {
  const socket = net.createConnection(80, 'www.google.com');

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    const info = socket.address();

    if (isAddressInfo(info)) callback(undefined, info.address);
    else callback(new Error('Socket address not found'), 'error');

    socket.end();
  });

  socket.on('error', (error) => callback(error, 'error'));
};
```

And if you only care about the object having an `address` property of type `string`, then you could use a simplified type guard:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgDsUYAaOGATzBTgEEkkoUCCBJYtCSmuuAGUIAYwDWZAL5w0UCCDgByYhFQAuUjEUBuAFC6A9AbgAVABb1+9CGjjUIWKHBEYcOAEYZxcAsADmxBgwjvQ4EBBiRDjAEnDAWkQQpHA2VBYEKGq6VnAAcmQA7tBiHAAKAMKuHl5icAC8iLpwcAYAVK1wAGLQcGYYxEjRxH5w-XAoUHJOrQZNcAAUE1NqcACik9CUIAR+K4pL0IoAlCsAbhDASHrNbR3dTn0DQyMYcEjABCIQpxMoSKPMVjsOAzObzAD6BygKywA3QwFISEoGEBbAIKwIMCgCL8Jzg50uekkekM7VMtHofiwGCg-zQsJEMGASRBs3pxEZzOIvUIgixOKYLDRcAAPCYAHzzU6uLCZUx46U4WVxIgmOAAMkQAKF7Ax-OGcGkCDmrGCUG58zmzSsqUVyrqDqUEHcACsUIzFFaNZqbbYpTL6IRRsRqEcAPwAOhROqIDoaikx2OGnuaRyJ+i+xExcD8ZHyMCKUBKpXqCxcbk84hW+cLxcqFZqR3q4sazUz2YIogk8AamgjIlYQRQ5SSpE5SXmAA4AAyURQFBcRvzhPw4FD9+THEnNTviMgRieKTNjrSUeZNuot43NNtJbMInil3fdqOo9jn7c34B+voEPlJvxBSBAh5gfCAjibctqnEeZYVQNAET+SgwNfGM0y9FAcAyZwqkrMR5lIAo1g2KB5kUYQ93wN8iBUeAeDg445yhLd9BvHwu33FABg-OZJHQuZn33Q9mLPKELxbKC8MWEimJI450OJXQgA)

```ts
function hasStringAddress <T>(value: T): value is T & { address: string } {
  return (
    typeof value === 'object'
    && typeof (value as any)?.address === 'string'
  );
}
```