# How to access localhost on mobile when using Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, server

So I've searched google a lot, and I've tried everything everyone is suggesting but nothing seems to be working.

I want to view my jekyll website on my mobile.

When I run jekyll it says server address: 127.0.0.1:4000

My computer's IP is 154.135.X.Y

I've opened up the port in the windows inbound rules

I've tried accessing from my mobile using both 154.135.X.Y:4000 and 127.0.0.1:4000 but to no avail.

Anyone know how I can access my jekyll site on mobile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to a locally built Jekyll Server using mobile devices in the LAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608466/connect-to-a-locally-built-jekyll-server-using-mobile-devices-in-the-lan)

Answer (score 24):

If your server address is 127.0.0.1 it means Jekyll is only listening on your localhost. You'll need to start Jekyll and instruct it to bind to port 4000 on ANY interface:

```
jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0
Configuration file: none
Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/private/tmp/test'
Configuration file: none
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

If you are accessing the computer from the web, you'll need to make sure your router forwards port 4000 to your PC.

If you are accessing the computer from your local LAN, make sure you accessing the private IP of your computer, and not the public IP.

Obviously you need to make sure there's not firewall that blocks incoming connections on your PC as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My PC is connected to my router via ethernet. My phone is connected via wifi. Does that mean I need to forward port 4000 on my router to my pc? How do you do this?

Answer (score 3):

- run `bundle exec jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0` or `jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0`
- open port 4000 in your laptop. (For windows add inbound rules exception for port 4000.)
- Find local ip address of laptop (https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-local-ip-address) like 192.168.1.109
- make sure mobile is connected to same wifi network as laptop. Open local-ip-address-laptop with port 4000 in mobile browser. i.e. https://192.168.1.109:4000
- Tada!
- You would still be able to access the site in your laptop with http://127.0.0.1:4000

---

TiP: use `{{site.baseurl}}/` to add images/assets in the pages and make sure there's no `url:~` key in **`_config.yml`**