# Google JavaScript API v3 unauthorized on 192.168 connection

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jekyll

I'm working on a project that uses the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to render directions on an integrated map.

The website it built with Jekyll and I run the server using the following command:

```
jekyll serve --host 192.168.2.7
```

The given IP address is the IP Address of the system running the server.

The reason I made it listen to that IP Address is because I want to test the application on my mobile devices, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12657655/1353158)

In the API Console I whitelisted `192.168.*`, so that any local connection can use the API.

However, when I go to that IP Address on my phone or computer, the API says the application is not authorized despite me having whitelisted it.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you set up your network to use hostnames instead of IP addresses?

Comment: @geocodezip I tried to connect to the hostname of the server (which is my macbook), but I get a 404 on my phone using `http://macbook-richard.local:4000`

Comment: Probably isn't publicly available.  It would need to be to get to it from your phone in all likelihood.  It would have to be defined in a nameserver that is used by your phone (or locally on the phone).

Comment: @geocodezip I have never worked with hostnames before and I don't understand how to set it up. Do I have to use do something with DNS to do that?

Comment: Can't help you with that (and this is not the correct forum for that question).

Comment: @geocodezip I assume that's a question for Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Jekyll serve

The `--hostname` flag doesn't exist. Use `--host 192.168.2.7` or `host: 192.168.2.7` in `_config.yml`. Target address will then be `192.168.2.7:4000` as 4000 is the default listening port for Jekyll webrick server.

### Google API withelist

It's not necessary to white list domain, as with no domain white listed you have **Any referer allowed**

### Google authorization

Verify that you've set your API key to something else than `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY` you are supposed to have something like this : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSytitittototoX7RhHn-drLRRYututu7eX2hVo`

If you still have problems, you can give a repository url to have it fixed quicker.
Happy Jekyll !

Comment: Oops! Excuse me, I wrote it wrong there. I did use `--host` (let me change that). And if I understand correct of what you're saying, if no referers are specified, it's an empty blacklist? (I just checked it, you're right. It seemed a bit counter-intuitive to me)

Answer (score 0):

192.168.2.7 is a [private IP address](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/g/192_168_0_0_def.htm) and is not publicly accessible.  To use that you will probably need to get a license.

Comment: I confirm that it work here on a LAN IP with no domain white listed in Google map API.