# iPhone testing: port forwarding and localhost

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, mobile-development

I'm trying to test our web app on iPhone. During the lifecycle our app is doing a call to a third-party api which allows calls only with a header 'origin: localhost'
On desktop it's not a problem. On Android I can set up [port forwarding](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#port-forwarding).
Can I do anything similar on iPhone? Is it possible?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657651/connect-device-to-mac-localhost-server). but it describes a way to use url like `[your pc name].local` which isn't what I need

Answer (score 0):

This might help: I was looking for a way to inspect (in desktop Chrome) a page (running on desktop *localhost*) loaded on Android and iOS phones connected via USB and found this guide https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/. A bit chaotic, yet, when following the additional steps for iOS11, it worked. I can see the Android Chrome and iOS Safari Tabs in desktop Chrome's inspector. I can also forward localhost to Android, sadly, not to iOS. But maybe it is a wrong configuration on my side and you can get it to work. Good luck!