# How can I test a website being developed locally from remote device (like an iPhone)?

Tags: wordpress, networking, web, mamp

I am developing a new WordPress theme and am doing this locally on my laptop using MAMP. On my laptop I can access the site at localhost:8800.

Is there a way I can visit this localhost site from my iPhone? I'd like to see what the theme looks like on mobile devices rather than just resizing my browser. Could this work if I make an ad hoc WiFi network between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the link 
[How do you access a website running on localhost from iPhone browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/how-do-you-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-iphone-browser)  here is the something you might be looking for.

or if you want to test your site on different devices http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ this link might be helpful ;)

Answer (score 4):

Head over to this site (http://xip.io/) and in your vhost setup the following replacing the IP address with your local IP:

```
#mysite.local
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/Development/mysite/www"
 ServerName mysite.local
 ServerAlias mysite.local.192.168.1.81.xip.io
  <Directory "/Users/me/Sites/Development/mysite/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then on your device head over to mysite.local.192.168.1.81.xip.io

Comment: Excellent, better than the accepted answer above as it easily lets you access all your local sites, thanks for the tip. Need to add that if you are using a custom port for your site (e.g. :8888), then you should add that in the browser as well, so mysite.local.192.168.1.81.xip.io:8888

Comment: Then what do you do for the certificate? Run a CA on the local web server and install its root certificate on each mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the iPhone is on the same network as the test server, just navigate to it's IP address on your phone.

**EDIT:** If you have multiple host names, then you can use [DNSMasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq). If you have a [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) router, add the following lines to the 'Additional DHCP Options' box in the Services page - and make sure DNSMasq is enabled :)

```
address=/dev/192.168.1.2
interface=lo
no-dhcp-interface=lo
```

This will direct .dev domains to 192.168.1.2 - adjust to suit your own needs.

Comment: Not work if your server using virtualhost (multiple host name)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to connect your mac and iphone to the same WiFi network.  Then get your IP address from System Preferences | Network.  It will be shown in the status section and will probably look something like 10.10.5.100.

Then on the iphone go to `http://10.10.5.100:8800`

Comment: Not work if your server using virtualhost (multiple host name)