# How to connect to Homestead which has multiple sites through mobile device?

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I'm working on a website in Laravel which I run on Homestead 0.2.0 and I want to try to connect to it with my phone and tablet so I can test the website on those devices.

So I was googling around, trying to look how to do so. However, I can't find any articles that take multiple sites into account.

I read somewhere however that some routers don't allow WiFi connected devices to connect to directly connected devices.

I have my sites mapped like so:

```
sites:
    - map: app1.local
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/app1/public
    - map: app2.local
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/app2/public
    - map: app3.local
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/app3/public
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: I use to have 1 site mapped and used foodshow plugin to tunnel my local development environment for viewing across devices. You can try tunneling your projects folder and then add /app1 to the url. It might work.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857012/470749 helps.

Answer (score 10):

## Solution

Add an entry `192.168.10.10` for the app you wanna test on your phone in the Homestead.yaml file and revision the Homestead machine. Then load `ipaddress:8000` on your phone

### Explanation

Upgrade to the latest Homestead, which maps *.app to 192.168.10.10

Then your `hosts` file has these entries:

```
192.168.10.10  app1.app app2.app app3.app
```

Let's say, your developing computer is using IP `192.168.0.102`.

You can browse on your phone to

```
192.168.0.102:8000
```

to load/test `app1.app` (first in alphabetical order)

### To test app3.app

Change your Homestead.yaml file
from:

```
map: app3.app
 to: /home/vagrant/projects/app3/public
```

to:

```
map: app3.app
 to: /home/vagrant/projects/app3/public
map: 192.168.10.10
 to: /home/vagrant/projects/app3/public
```

Simply change the entry and revision  the Homestead machine to test another app on your phone.