# Laravel 5 Homestead Multiple Sites on Local Network

Tags: laravel-5, homestead

I have two Laravel projects on a Homestead machine.

Homestead.yaml

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
- map: blog.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Blog/public
```

and /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
192.168.10.10   blog.app
```

And everything works as expected. But when I want to access sites from a phone on a local network and go to

```
192.168.1.100:8000
```

It takes me to a Blog project. **Is there a way for all projects to be accessible at all times?**

I read this [How to connect to Homestead which has multiple sites through mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426640/how-to-connect-to-homestead-which-has-multiple-sites-through-mobile-device), but you have to pick one project to be accessible. And you have to edit Homestead.yaml and reload vagrant every time you want to swap projects.

Comment: Its correct.. You can't access the multiple sites configured in homestead. If you want to access, you may try the services like ngrok.

Comment: @Anandhan, do you know *why* you can't? With port forwarding and hosts files, this doesn't seem like something that should be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured this out myself, and I have posted answers here ([Homestead cant access second site remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461216/homestead-cant-access-second-site-remotely/53717255#53717255)) and here ([Laravel homestead multiple sites choose which one is locally accesable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334226/laravel-homestead-multiple-sites-choose-which-one-is-locally-accesable/53717306#53717306)).

In short:

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
  port: 81
- map: blog.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Blog/public

ports:
  - send: 8100
    to: 81
```

Then access your `homestead.app` project via `http://192.168.1.100:8100`.

Comment: The one caveat: From the host machine, you would obviously need to access the `homestead.app` application on port 81 instead of the normal default of 80.