# Homestead cant access second site remotely

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, vagrantfile

I have one site setup fine, but the second can't be accessed remotely:

My YAML:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: app.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/app1/public
    - map: app2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/app2/public
      port: 8100

ports:
    - host: 81
    - guest: 8100
```

I can access the first site using my IP easily - `http://192.168.0.5/` but the second one cannot share the same port, so I've added `81 -> 8100`.

When I try to reprovision my homestead vagrant box it says:
    There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

```
vm:
* Forwarded port definitions require a "host" and "guest" value
* Ports to forward must be 1 to 65535
* Ports to forward must be 1 to 65535
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in your yaml you have `192.168.10.10` and you can access the site from `http://192.168.0.5/` .I think you have other VMs running or something else

Comment: No `0.5` is an example of my laptop's local IP, I am trying to access this from a mobile app

Comment: Basically I want to know how to access two separate sites, running on the same homestead instance, from a remote device.

Comment: generally you'll manage this through the host `host` file and add 2 alias on the VM IP with each of the site name and will access the sites using the site name rather than IP

Comment: Yes but remotely I cant write `http://app2.app`, I have to write `http://192.168.0.5/` and then I always get the first app rather than the second. Is there no way to handle this with a different port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service [xip.io](http://xip.io) can make short work of this. Here's how:

As an example, I have the following Homesite app setup, 'rentmanager.test'. This is the first application I provisioned on Homestead, so it's the default route. To access this from my local network, all I have to do is go to:

```
http://rentmanager.test.192.168.5.124.xip.io:8000
```

Where 'rentmanager.test.' is the name of my Laravel application on Homestead, '192.166.5.124.' is my IP address on the local network, 'xip.io:8000' is the redirect service domain and the needed port to access the app (8000) outside of the default routing that Homestead sets up.

Now, this works fine out of the box with the first site you provision, but what happens if we have more than one site? That requires a little more legwork. Let's assume we've got a second app called 'sitescanner.test' that we want to access. If I try to access the same URL above with the new app URL, you'll see I'm still served the first application! Let's resolve that as well.

First, you're going to need to add an additional rule to your hosts file. So, assuming our new app is called 'sitescanner.test':

```
# Vagrant Sites External Access

192.168.10.10 sitescanner.test.192.168.5.124.xip.io
```

Once that's in place then we have to update the provisioning scripts in Homestead to create the correct virtual host entries so Homestead knows how to route the request. To do that, we'll edit your Homestead.yaml. Under the 'sites:' directive:

```
- map: sitescanner.test
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/sitescanner/public   
- map: sitescanner.test.192.168.5.124.xip.io
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/sitescanner/public
```

Once this is complete, simply 'vagrant halt' (if it's already running), then 'vagrant up --provision' and you should be able to access your site from

```
http://sitescanner.test.192.168.5.124.xip.io:8000
```

Anywhere on your network! Hope this helps.

While I'm thinking about it, there is a final consideration for this configuration:

- You may want to set a static IP address on your host machine if possible. If you're being assigned a dynamic IP address via DHCP it's possible (and likely) for this configuration to eventually break if you're ever assigned a new IP.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael this was exactly what I needed! Very thorough answer too.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation found at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead

you don't need to specify ports when adding multiple sites

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: another.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/another/public
```

then add the following to your hosts file

```
192.168.10.10  homestead.app
192.168.10.10  another.app
```

make sure to run `vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: Thats exactly what I have, but how do I access another.app from my mobile phone?

Comment: If you are running on a mac and iphone you can set this up using a tool called SquidMan http://squidman.net/squidman/

Comment: There is also a way with vagrant to share a site to ngrok using share "app"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which version of Laravel or Homestead you are using, but this is possible. With the Homestead versions documented for Laravel 5.6 or 5.7, you were 95% of the way to having this complete.

1. Instead of using `port: 8100` in your `sites` configuration, you should have used `port: 81`.
2. Instead of `guest` and `host`, use `send` and `to`.

I used the exact same setup as you except for those two differences, and it works for me.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: app.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/app1/public
    - map: app2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/app2/public
      port: 81

ports:
    - send: 8100
      to: 81
```

You would then be able to access your app via `http://app2.app:8100` if your hosts file has an entry for `app2.app` or via `http://192.168.0.5:8100` if you aren't using the hosts file.

Comment: The one caveat: From the host machine, you would obviously need to access the `app2.app` application on port 81 instead of the normal default of 80.