# I can't connect to my localhost on my computer to my iPad

Tags: ipad, ip, localhost, wamp

I'm performing quality control on a project that I can access via localhost on my computer with wamp running. I'm also testing on an iPad to view issues, but I'm having trouble since Safari is giving me the "cannot open page because it could not connect to the server".

ipconfig and whatismyip.com give me 2 different IP addresses, but I've tried to use both with port 80,8080, 6969 (just trying everything at this point).

Also, I've restarted wamp services, turned off/on firewall, and have edited httpconf files to allow for all.

I've never done this task before so I might just not be going in the correct order, but I've been looking online for solutions for the past 90 minutes.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your localhost on your computer VIA your iPad?

Comment: I'm trying to access my computer's localhost (running wampserver) on my iPad to test a project.

Comment: Here is how I do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857012/470749

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you are on the same network.
2. Your local IP on your computer will be in the same range as your router.. usually 192.168.x.x
3. You need to add the port assigned by wamp to the ip address
4. So if you determined your pc had the address 192.168.1.10 and your wamp port is 8080.. then the address you would enter on your iPad would be 192.168.1.10:8080

Sorry if this is too basic, just starting from the beginning

Comment: On step 2, when I run ipconfig on command prompt, my ip address is 10.180.xxx.xx.xxx and on whatismyip.com it's 68.xxx.xxx.xx. which is the correct one?

Comment: local ip ranges usually start with 192 or 10. So i would assume its 10.180.xxx.xx.xxx. Whatsmyip.com is outside of your local network and will only see the ip of your isp, not your local ip.

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error even though my port is 80. This is very weird, haha. Maybe because I'm on a public network? (Apartment supplies "free wifi")

Comment: I would not expect this to work on a public wifi setup. They general try to make it so machines can't access each other for security reasons. I also would not expect wamp to be using port 80, since that is generally the default web port, but maybe it does, I don't use wamp.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: you could maybe set up an adhoc wireless network on your pc and join it from your iPad for testing... http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this sounds like a good idea. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Also, the issue was that I was on a public wifi network. When I went into work this morning, everything connected in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I also had same problems before. If you are on a WIFI, then it is very easy to solve.

1. Open the Wireless Settings Page (Generally at 192.168.1.1).
2. Login with your username/password (default username/password : admin/admin).
3. Go to Wireless Basic Settings where you can edit Wireless Network Name (SSID) or enable/disable wifi or change settings like bandwidth or 802.11 mode.
4. Uncheck EnableMulti AP isolation.
5. Enjoy.

-Peace :)