# Vue application running on Digitalocean times out in browser

Tags: node.js, vue.js, digital-ocean, ufw

First time I try to use a node.js droplet on Digitalocean: I have a vue.js application running on port 8080, but it times out when I try to load the masterpiece in the browser (I don't have a domain so I use the [server IP]:8080 to access it).

I made sure 8080 is open in the firewall (ufw):

[image: screen]

Netstat -pln gave the result seen in the screenshot below, a node program is running but nothing is named vue in case that would be required:

[image: screen]

Tried `export HOST=0.0.0.0` on advice from a friend, but didn't seem to do anything.

Tested `curl 127.0.0.1:8080` from the digitalocean console and it works correctly.

The browser error message is `err _ connection timed out`.

Any tips on how to get this to show in the browser? As I'm not experienced in working with servers please give me step by step instructions. Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the vue application? Using the webpack dev server (npm run dev)?

Comment: If so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412137/how-to-get-access-to-webpack-dev-server-from-devices-in-local-network

Comment: @Geert-Jan Great, I think that should solve it. It is webpack dev server yes. I start the application with the command npm start which runs npm run dev.

Comment: Great. Glad to help