# how to host OHIF viewer publicly

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have download OHIF code and build using `yarn install` on both root folder and viewer folder inside platform folder in Windows 10.
I can access the OHIF viewer successfully @localhost:3000 and also ipaddress:3000, but am not able to access it from a different machine using ipaddress:3000. 
I am able to run various other application on different ports and access it publicly but in case of OHIF it doesn't work.
Am I missing anything?
And one more problem is OHIF creates almost 50MB file from 'yarn run dev' command and everytime I have to load 50MB on page load. Is there any way to compress the OHIF library by building it.

Answer (score 0):

> am not able to access it from a different machine using ipaddress:3000

I believe you would need to tweak the WebPack configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35419631/1867984

The `webpack-dev-server` is not meant to host the application for production use. Ideally, you build the files and host them using a production ready web server. You have a lot of different options here. Check out: https://docs.ohif.org/deployment/recipes/static-assets.html

> I have to load 50MB on page load. Is there any way to compress the OHIF library by building it.

If you run the production build with minification and treeshaking, the size drops to 15 MB. You can further lower this by pruning any extensions you don't intend to use.

Also, most of these assets aren't render blocking. *Some* codesplitting is used to lazy load portions of the application after the critical portions are loaded. This could still be improved.