# test local website on mobile device

Tags: ios, iphone, localhost

I am trying to test my website on my iphone and ipad over my local wifi network connection. I am on windows 10 and this computer is connected via Ethernet. I have typed in my host machines ip and even created an inbound rule to no avail. I have looked at many examples such as this one [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/how-do-you-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-iphone-browser). I simply get an error message on my iphone "safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server." Any advice?

Comment: Have you connected your PC and phone via wifi???

Comment: The pc is connected with ethernet cable and the iphone and ipad are on my local wifi. The pc and devices are on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Find out the IP of the machine which hosts the website (ipconfig)
2. Identify on which port the website listens (usually 80)
3. Ping the server from another host and see it's successful
4. Still on the other host - run tcping to the desired port to see if it's open. You can download tcping from here - [TCPing download](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php)
5. If it's all good and it's still not working maybe try to use another port

Comment: How can I identify which port the website listens? It's not a website on a server somewhere. Just on my local machine. It's website I am building.

Comment: Even if it's a local machine it still needs a port, that's how it works.
Try running netstat -a | FIND "LISTENING" command from command prompt (start --> run -->cmd) to see your open ports. see [How to read NETSTAT](https://sites.google.com/site/xiangyangsite/home/technical-tips/linux-unix/networks-related-commands-on-linux/how-to-read-netstat--an-results) for more info.

Comment: Ok so I need the port my computer is using? If so where do find that information? Thanks.

Comment: Usually it's port 80, depends on the web server port that runs on your computer. Try to look for open ports using netstat (look at the comment above).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your computer and iPhone are on the same subnet. Are they connected to *the same* router? Look in the network configuration settings and do they have the IPs with the same subnet? (192.168.4.2 and 192.168.4.6 share the subnet 192.168.4 while 192.168.5.3 and 192.168.6.7 do not).
2. Is it possible for your computer to access the website locally? That is to say, type `http://localhost:port` in the Safari to check if website works.

Comment: yeah sorry I have no idea how to check if my iphone and computer are on the same subnet. I am simply trying to view the website that is located on my computer from my iphone. Both are on the same network. I want to do this so I can see what the website looks like on a mobile device. I have zero networking knowledge.

Comment: ok I figured it out. Yes they are on the same subnet and on the same router.