# How to specify a port to run a create-react-app based project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-server

My project is based on [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-bootstrap). `npm start` or `yarn start` by default will run the application on **port 3000** and there is no option of specifying a port in the package.json.

How can I specify a port of my choice in this case? I want to run two of this project simultaneously (for testing), one in port `3005` and other is `3006`

Comment: Just quickly mentioning here that for Next.js projects you'll just use `next -p 3005` if anyone else fall here looking for the same thing.

Comment: In my case `package.json` is using `yarn`  `"start": "yarn run react-scripts start"`  , so how to add `port` in this case ?

Comment: See`Adding Development Environment Variables In .env` - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/4cdd5ac/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Answer (score 1338, accepted):

If you don't want to set the [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40714921/4249707), another option is to modify the `scripts` part of package.json from:

```json
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

**Linux** (tested on Ubuntu 14.04/16.04) and **MacOS** (tested by aswin-s on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4):

```json
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

or (may be) more general solution by [IsaacPak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1991020/isaac-pak)

```json
"start": "export PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

**Windows** [JacobEnsor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389990/jacob-ensor)'s solution

```json
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
```

**cross-env lib** works everywhere. See Aguinaldo Possatto's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48669909/4249707) for details

**Update due to the popularity of my answer:** Currently I prefer to use environment variables saved in [`.env`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42232944/4249707) file(useful to store sets of variables for different `deploy` configurations in a convenient and readable form). Don't forget to add `*.env` into `.gitignore` if you're still storing your secrets in `.env` files. [Here](https://12factor.net/config) is the explanation of why using environment variables is better in the most cases. [Here](https://diogomonica.com/2017/03/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-env-variables-for-secret-data/) is the explanation of why storing secrets in environment is bad idea.

Comment: For windows set PORT=3005 && react-scripts start worked for me :)

Comment: You could also install the `cross-env` package and do `"start": "cross-env PORT=3006 react-scripts start"`. That would work in every environment.

Comment: @MauricioLeal IMO installation of the additional package instead of simple and understandable fix looks like overkill

Comment: @ElRuso If the project is only used in a specific environment, I agree, it is overkill. The use case for something like `cross-env` is when you have several developers working on different systems. Maybe some prefer MACs, and some others prefer Windows. Or, another scenario, all developers use Windows but you want to add an Environment Variable that will be run on your CI/CD server that runs Ubuntu. I hope that helps.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS- "start": "PORT=8081 react-scripts start", 
Windows 10 - "start": "SET PORT=8081 && react-scripts start"

Comment: For MAC this works:
`"start": "export PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"`

Comment: Please adopt the habit of using `cross-env`. Especially when it comes to open source, not only is it crappy to basically say "You use operating system X, so we don't want you", you also limit the number of people able to contribute.

Comment: On a Mac OS environment (or Ubuntu I gather should work as well), you need to add && between commands or terminate each command with a ";".  Like so:

"start": "export PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"

(the answer provided by @mim

Comment: Update:  `for windows` use `"start": "set \"PORT=2022\" && react-scripts start"`

Comment: `.env files should be checked into source control (with the exclusion of .env*.local).` . See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/4cdd5ac/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: Does this work for host too?

Answer (score 535):

Here is another way to accomplish this task.

Create a `.env` file at your project root and specify port number there. Like:

```
PORT=3005
```

Comment: Using a .env file is supported out of the box with create-react-app. Just be sure not to check .env into source control if you put sensitive information in there.

Comment: The is the method described in the create-react-app [README.md](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/4cdd5ac/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration)

Comment: @Don This seems a bit confusing. The FB guys are recommending the opposite... https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Comment: @carkod Actually, they are saying to put sensitive data in a file *other* than `.env`. In Their case they recommend using `.env.local` which you should not check into source control, so that you can safely check `.env` into source control. So the same advice still applies.

Comment: I like this answer better, since it makes use of the configuration options available, while the other solutions feel more like tricks/hacks.

Comment: This works for MacOSX and Windows with the same package.json file.

Answer (score 138):

Create a file with name `.env` in the main directory besides`package.json` and set `PORT` variable to desired port number.

For example:

**.env**

```
PORT=4200
```

You can find the documentation for this action here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration

Answer (score 73):

You could use [**cross-env**](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) to set the port, and it will work on Windows, Linux and Mac.

```bash
yarn add -D cross-env
```

then in package.json the start link could be like this:

```json
"start": "cross-env PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.
Something that can work well on most common platforms for example my home setup is Windows and work is Mac.

Comment: Best solution if the whole team need to run the code

Comment: I actually use the `dotenv` cli. I install it globally so I don't have to pollute the package.json with tooling specific to my machine. I just run applications with `dotenv yarn start`

Answer (score 59):

**Method 1**

Create .env File in the root folder of a project

[image]

Set like this

```
PORT=3005
```

**Method 2**

[image]

In *package.json*

```
set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start
```

Comment: its `export PORT=3006` for mac

Comment: This is the most perfect solution for those who want a permanent change without specifying port each time or wanna use react with pm2. Thanks, you have saved my day.

Comment: For Ubuntu22, it is        "start": "PORT=80 react-scripts start",

Answer (score 44):

You can specify a environment variable named `PORT` to specify the port on which the server will run.

```
$ export PORT=3005 #Linux
$ $env:PORT=3005 # Windows - Powershell
```

Comment: i will run two react application, one must be on port 3005 and the other should be on 3006

Comment: @lem You can open two consoles, set environment variables to 3005 and 3006 in each one of them and run the application.

Comment: `"start": "set PORT=3005 react-scripts start"` just set the port but doesn't run the app

Comment: @legnoban add an && in between the 2 commands. `"start": "set PORT=3005 && react-scripts start"`

Answer (score 38):

just run below command

```
PORT=3001 npm start
```

Comment: works with yarn start too.

Answer (score 23):

In your `package.json`, go to scripts and use `--port 4000` or `set PORT=4000`, like in the example below:

`package.json` (Windows):

```json
"scripts": {
   "start": "set PORT=4000 && react-scripts start"
}
```

`package.json` (Ubuntu):

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "export PORT=4000 && react-scripts start"
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a little prose to explain the intent of your code.

Comment: One command for all OSes: `"start": "cross-env PORT=4000 react-scripts start"` (requires https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Answer (score 22):

For windows, you can directly run this command on cmd

```
set PORT=3001 && npm start
```

Comment: IT will go to infinite loop

Comment: This won't work at command line except overriding it

Comment: this code runs on cmd without doing any extra configuration

Comment: This method works perfectly for me, with the bonus of not needing to create or modify any files.

Answer (score 17):

You can modify your ***scripts*** inside ***package.json***:

***-on MacOs :***

```json
"scripts": {
     "start": "PORT=9002 react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     ...     
}
```

-***on Windows***

```json
"scripts": {
     "start": "set PORT=9002 && react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for Linux Elementary OS

```
"start": "PORT=3500 react-scripts start"
```

Comment: This one just works fine!

Answer (score 11):

For my windows folks I discovered a way to change ReactJS port to run on any port you want.Before running the server go to

```
 node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
```

In it, search for the line below and change the port number to your desired port

```
 var DEFAULT_PORT = process.env.PORT || *4000*;
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Beware: changes you make inside the `node_modules` directory will be blown away when the packages are updated. Probably best to use one of the other answers.

Comment: upvoted because it gives insight on where they set this file (ended up here while I was simply trying to understand what create-react-app does behind the curtain)

Comment: @ozgeneral You can also eject the app and have a more complete control. Though there are chances someone might mess things up but it will  give you a scripts/start.js which is the same file as above and prevents update failure.

Comment: I think this is a terrible idea. Portability of the project is damaged

Answer (score 10):

Why not just

```
PORT=3030 npm run start
```

Answer (score 10):

To specify a port to run a Create React App (CRA) based project, you can utilize the PORT environment variable. By default, CRA uses port 3000, but you can override it with a custom port number. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open a terminal or command prompt
2. Navigate to the root directory of your CRA project.
3. Set the PORT environment variable to your desired port number. For example, to run on port 8000, you can use the following command:

On macOS/Linux:

```
PORT=8000 npm start
```

On Windows (Command Prompt)

```
set PORT=8000 && npm start
```

On Windows (PowerShell):

```
$env:PORT = 8000; npm start
```

This command sets the PORT environment variable to 8000 before executing the npm start command, which starts the development server.

Answer (score 8):

Just update a bit in `webpack.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 3000 // <--- Add this line and choose your own port number
}
```

then run `npm start` again.

Answer (score 7):

Lot of answers have not mentioned one key part for windows. For me what worked to run react app in specified port in windows was with following command. You can change port number from example below. Dont forget to use &&.

```
set PORT=4200 && react-scripts start
```

Answer (score 5):

you can find default port configuration at start your app

```
yourapp/scripts/start.js
```

scroll down and change the port to whatever you want

```
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 4000;
```

hope this may help you ;)

Comment: There is no scripts dir in my create-react-app

Comment: For this answer to work, you need to `yarn eject` first.

Answer (score 5):

How about giving the port number while invoking the command without need to change anything in your application code or environment files? That way it is possible running and serving same code base from several different ports.

like:

`$ export PORT=4000 && npm start`

You can put the port number you like in place of the example value `4000` above.

You can use same expression in the **package.json scripts** too.

like:

`"start": "export PORT=4000 react-scripts start"`

But for that latter one you will need to change the `package.json`, however, for the former one you will not change anything except port value in invocation from a command line.

Comment: Correct, though this will work only for the session. But parametrizing this proving the port number will allow to each time provide a port(in case we don't know which are busy

Comment: I guess you can parametrize this too but at the end you will be saying say `npm start -p 4000` instead of `export PORT=4000 && npm start` from a command line.

Answer (score 5):

Can specify Port in package.json , by defining port number:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"}
```

OR
Can specify port when running the script in terminal :

```
PORT=3003 npm start
```

Comment: Or create a .env file with `PORT=3006`

Comment: On Windows: `"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"`

Answer (score 4):

To summarize, we have three approaches to accomplish this:

1. Set an environment variable named "PORT"
2. Modify the "start" key under "scripts" part of package.json
3. Create a .env file and put the PORT configuration in it

The most portable one will be the last approach. But as mentioned by other poster, add .env into .gitignore in order not to upload the configuration to the public source repository.

Answer (score 3):

Changing in my package.json file `"start": "export PORT=3001 && react-scripts start"` worked for me too and I'm on macOS 10.13.4

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
npm start port=30022
```

Comment: Don't work for me, in Ubuntu machine (Digital Ocean)

Comment: @Ethan , it did work however it added my wish port number on top of the existing one , any ideas how to delete the 8081 and add 8000 
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 8000

Answer (score 3):

In case you have already done `npm run eject`, go to scripts/start.js and change port in `const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;` (3000 in this case) to whatever port you want.

Answer (score 3):

I just create .env in the root of my project and change the PORT=3001

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my react project had two files: `.env` and `.env.development`.

I added this to `.env.development` to get it working with the `npm start` command for development:

```
PORT=3001
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to be able to specify a port other than `3000`, either as a command line parameter or an environment variable.

Right now, the process is pretty involved:

1. Run `npm run eject`
2. Wait for that to finish
3. Edit `scripts/start.js` and find/replace `3000` with whatever port you want to use
4. Edit `config/webpack.config.dev.js` and do the same
5. `npm start`

Comment: yes, I'd like to be able to specify port as a command line variable, (only) when I've got another server already using 3000.

Comment: Read the other answers, no need to eject

Answer (score 2):

In Windows it can be done in 2 ways.

1. Under " \node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js" , search for 
   "DEFAULT_PORT" and add the desire port number.

   E.g : const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 9999;
2. In package.json , appent the below line.
   "start": "set PORT=9999 && react-scripts start"
   Then start the application using NPM start. It will start the application in 9999 
   port.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell on Windows (Run as Administrator):

(cd to your CRA app root folder)

$env:PORT=3002 ; npm start

Answer (score 2):

In case you run `npm start` in a Dockerfile, and you can't map ports in a `docker run`, like doing something like `-p 3001:3000`, this works:

```
FROM node

ENV PORT=3001

# whatever here, COPY .. etc.

CMD npm start
```

Or you can pass the port number as an argument in a `docker buid`:

```
FROM node

ARG PORT=${PORT}
ENV PORT=${PORT}

# whatever here, COPY .. etc.

CMD npm start
```

using `--build-arg` in `docker buid`

```
docker build --build-arg PORT=3001 .
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the webpack.config.js and add the port you want to run this on. This is what you are looking for:

> 'devServer:
> { port: 3005,
> historyApiFallback: true,
> },

and

> output: {
> publicPath: "http://localhost:3005/",
> },

Answer (score 0):

You have need to update your **package.json** to specify different PORT

In the script section replace start command like following: -

*Make sure mentioned PORT is free to listen*

"start": "export PORT=3001; react-scripts start"

Your application will start at http://localhost:3001

Thanks

Comment: The [accepted answer from 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848/19068) says all that, and goes into more detail about platform specific differences. If you're going to answer an old question, please make sure that your answer **adds something useful**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Edit your `project/package.json` file.

Go to the `scripts` section. Update the value corresponding to `start` key to the following.

`"start": "export PORT=4000; react-scripts start"`

Now the your React app will be running at `http://localhost:4000/`

Note: You can use any port number, But better to [avoid well-known port numbers](https://www.webopedia.com/reference/well-known-tcp-port-numbers/) like 22,21,80 etc.

Comment: `start": "set PORT=4000 && react-scripts start`
this worked for me.