# Unable to run react js project

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a project build using react js 
I want to execute it locally

What I have done so far :

1) installed node.js (windows 64 bit)

2) Followed till Step 3 from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

Now I have

1) c://program files /nodejs/node_modules

2) Desktop/reactApp/node_modules

I places my project folder inside reactApp/ . so package.json is at reactApp/package.json

now when i try to run `npm start`

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\reactApp>npm start

> liquid@0.1.0 start C:\Users\jitendra\Desktop\reactApp
> PORT=8080 react-scripts start

'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! liquid@0.1.0 start: `PORT=8080 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the liquid@0.1.0 start script 'PORT=8080 react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the liquid package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     PORT=8080 react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs liquid
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls liquid
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jitendra\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-03T08_13_40_048Z-debug.log
```

Here is my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "liquid",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "google-map-react": "^0.23.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^0.9.5",
    "react-sortable-tree": "^0.1.17",
    "react-table": "^5.5.3",
    "reactstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && aws s3 sync build/ s3://xxx.co/1micro",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "homepage": "http://xxx.co/1micro"
}
```

Comment: run an admin command prompt, go to the root of the project folder and run `npm install`, sometimes this fixes some issues with dependencies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a port to run a create-react-app based project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project)

Comment: @MayankShukla ,El Ruso 's answer is same as my json file . and error shows at the same line . May be it does not work on windows .

Comment: You have clearly used a package.json that is not of your project, if you really did follow the guide you are saying you woudln't be having  those extra dependencies. Seems like you have mixed two projects. Please give the link to project you are trying to start

Comment: react-scripts is in correspondece with the project created using create-react-app, you if you are creating one yourself, you should be following the rest of the steps too from the link, i.e to configure webpack

Comment: @Zeus , I just installed all the things from given tutorial . then i replaced projects's package.json file with the one generated through the tutorial 's steps . Am i still missing any thing ?

Comment: @NiraliJoshi You cannot just replace package.json of a project with other one. Follow each step, do not copy paste the full package.json, as you will run `npm install` package.json will change it self. Just copy paste parts of package.json when the tutorial tells you to. Restart doing the project from the start following each step this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `.env` file at your project root and specify port number there `PORT=3005`
then in package json start script use like this `"start": "react-scripts start"`

Sample package json file below

```
{
  "name": "r",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: It says , 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Hope you executed `npm install` to get the dependencies to your machine first

Comment: Yes, I have react and react-dom folder inside node_modules folder. when I try npm ls react-scripts , it says `-- UNMET DEPENDENCY react-scripts@^0.9.5

npm ERR! missing: react-scripts@^0.9.5, required by liquid@0.1.0

Comment: @NiraliJoshi can you put `react-scripts` into `dev dependencies` instead of in `dependencies` and try `npm install` again

Comment: @NiraliJoshi I have added a sample packagejson which would help

Comment: npm install again at my project folder  ? are you sure ? npm install or npm start ?

Comment: Once you move the `react-scripts` to `devdependencies` execute `npm install` because according to the error stack you mentioned it seems `react-scripts` dependencies is not yet installed, if `npm install` gets success do `npm start`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143256/discussion-between-nirali-joshi-and-keshshan).

Answer (score 3):

That PORT command will only work on Unix. Try opening a command window and setting the port variable in a windows way, I think it's (in powershell):

```
$env:PORT=3005
```

or, in a normal command window:

```
set PORT=3005
```

which you can then check works by running:

```
echo %PORT%
```

which should return 3005. Then, navigate to your reactApp directory and run:

```
react-scripts start
```

Comment: should i run $env:PORT=3005 at my project root directory ?

Comment: it says , The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @NiraliJoshi Run it on Windows Powershell $env:PORT=3005

Comment: Updated my answer. It doesn't matter where you are when you run the set environment params like PORT

Comment: @Wayneio before you didn't mention about set command which can be used in cmd, but u was mentioning `$env:PORT=3005` without exactly telling where to execute that was the problem so mentioned it

Comment: @Wayneio PORT set. but react-scripts start says -- 'react - scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @NiraliJoshi Okay, so my answer solved that problem. What you mention is a new problem. I'm not sure what that's doing. I'd look at maybe a simpler React.js project if you're just starting out

Answer (score 1):

**if above solutions does not fixed your problem, try the following this worked for me:**

if you are not able to start react js project then do the following steps:

1. open **package.json** file
2. inside **script** replace the **start** command with below **"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"**