# How to specify a port number in a create-react-app based project in production?

Tags: reactjs, reverse-proxy, create-react-app

I am deploying a website that will have a few react projects that were built with create-react-app.  Each project will be on its own webpage: e.g.: mywebsite.com/project1, mywebsite.com/project.  I am setting up an nginx reverse proxy on an Ubuntu server (which I understand how to configure), but I am not sure how to specify port numbers for each of my create-react-app projects so that each of them has a unique port.  Can anyone shed light on how to do this?  Thanks!

PS - I have seen threads such as this one - [How to specify a port to run a create-react-app based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project), but I do not see how this solution can be applied in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server you start with `npm start` command in create-react-app is webpack dev server. It only meant to use while development and you shouldn't use that in a production environment.

Instead, you can easily host a CRA app with a simple static file server which can [easily configure with nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/) without a reverse proxy or changing the port of dev server. You simply need run `npm run build` command and deploy content of `build` folder to the appropriate folder of your static file server. You can read more about this in [the documentation of CRA](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment).

Also, make sure that you [specify the `homepage` in your `package.json`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths) before building the project, since you are going to host your app in a relative path like `mywebsite.com/project1`. Because CRA assumes your app is hosted at the server root with default settings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Tharaka, Thanks so much for your response!  Hosting the CRA apps with a static file server is definitely the most efficient and straightforward way to deploy my website.  I appreciate the tip on the homepage line as well.  I've just deployed a CRA project, and it is working!!