# How use localhost access without specify the port number

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I want to access localhost without specify the port number in the URL
http://localhost instead of http://localhost:8080.

if I set the default port number 80 that this kind of  XAMPP Port 80 in use by “Unable to open process” with PID 4 [duplicate]

then now I cant use 80 and open http://localhost.

i can fix “Unable to open process” with PID 4 [duplicate] error changing port to 8080. but I want to open localhost http://localhost instead of http://localhost:8080.

Can any one give me any idea about that.

Comment: That is not possible. Browsers will only use the defined default ports (80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS) automatically - if you use any other ports, then you must explicitly specify them. The only way to get this to work, is if you set up a proxy server listening on port 80, that then internally forwards your requests to 8080. But if you are able to do that, then you would be able to make it work on port 80 to begin with. Find out _what_ is using port 80, and stop it from doing so (one of the usual suspects is Skype, that has options not to occupy ports 80/443 in the settings.)

Comment: my 80 use called by system. when i check with task manager PID 4 for the system. I Right click on that process and click "End Process Tree".  then again I cant open my apache

Comment: Use `netstat -b` (start command prompt with admin rights), it will show you what executable files are behind the processes that listen on a port.

Comment: it is not appear any process as use by 80

Comment: I think this has already been answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project