# How to set React Custom Port like 3129

Tags: reactjs

My project is based on create-react-app. npm start or yarn start by default will run the application on port 3000 and there is no option of specifying a port in the package.json.

Comment: What OS? You have to set the PORT environment variable.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/242

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a port to run a create-react-app based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Just update a bit in **webpack.config.js**:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 3000 // <--- Add this line and choose your own port number
  }
```

then run `npm start` again
This will set the default port for that app to the on you specified

> Alternatively:
>   modify part of package.json from:

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

for Linux and MacOS to:

```
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

Windows to:

```
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
```

Answer (score 1):

With create react app, you can create a file called `.env` at the root level, and put the following code inside it :

> PORT=3129

Answer (score 1):

Add .env file in source folder and add entry like below

```
PORT=9001
```

Answer (score -1):

run this code

```
yarn start --port 30022
```