# Getting a 404 error when trying to setup WebStorm IDE JavaScript debugger for a create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When following an article entitled, ["Debugging React apps created with Create React App in WebStorm"](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/), the Debugger says it's connected to the JetBrains IDE Chrome Extension, but I can't get breakpoints to execute when using port 3000 and when I try to use the default debug port 63342 a 404 error is shown.

---

Here is a recording of my settings in Chrome and Webstorm 2016.2 IDE when trying to debug: http://recordit.co/MQ3LICuUIc

---

Steps Taken:

I've created a new JS debug configuration with the name 'ERS React Debug', the browser set to Chrome, and I've tried using the following URLs in the configuration:

http://localhost:3000/

http://localhost:3000/ers_react/public/index.html

http://localhost:63342/ers_react/public/index.html

(YT video I watched used the debug port, which is what is in my recording)

I also setup the mapping to webpack:///src as recommend in the article.

Comment: Try running the app on port 63342, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848/1039555

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KartikKaushik. When I change the port number using the .env file to the same port number as the debugger and run

    `npm restart`

I get the error

    `? Something is already running on port 63342.`

Just to be sure it was the IDE I ran

    `netstat -a -b`

and verified it was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Default ReactJS app created with `create-react-app` is designed to be hosted on webpack server started with `react-scripts start`, that builds the application and starts the server. You won't be able to open this application on the simple built-in webserver (`localhost:63342`).

To be able to debug modern React app, you need upgrading Webstorm to the most recent version - debugging will work out of the box. Fot Webstorm 2016.2, you can try specifying URL mappings... For `"react-scripts": "1.0.17"`, it should be `http://localhost:3000/static/js/full/path to project`, like `http://localhost:3000/static/js/C:/WebstormProjects/untitled` if the project path is `C:/WebstormProjects/untitled` should work:

[image]

Note that you would need to refresh the browser page to get breakpoints in code executed on pagfe loading hit