# Detaching React js project on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

I have created two React projects using React Js. The both of them are for different purposes. One is successfully running on `1.2.3.4:3000` here the port is default (`3000`) But I have another react project with `port 4000`. Now how can I run or deploy the second React js(client) on port 4000?

Folder structure

```
/
|-- adminReact (port 3000)
|
|--clientReact (port 4000)
```

Comment: How did you deploy the first React project? What build tools are you using (webpack, create-react-app, parcel, etc.. ), if any?

Comment: @DerekNguyen, I used create-react-app

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848/10340970

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a port to run a create-react-app based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou all

I managed this problem with the hekp of linux `screen`.

I created two screens with meaningful name. Then O run the react projects on different port.

`screen -R adminReact` 
 Then go inside the adminRea t directory then start the adminReact project. After successful running, I pressed `ctrl + a + d` to detach from the screen.
Then type `exit` will close the screen.

Then takea new putty session. After that create a new screen `screen -R clientReact` for the clien react projects.Then go inside the folder then start the project, after successful running press `ctrl + a + d` to detach the screen.

That's it