# Unable to run a development build of a React app in a Docker container using node:alpine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have a React app which is based on Facebook's `create-react-app`. During development I run it on a specific local port (60001). To achieve this I changed the default `start` script in the `scripts` part of my *package.json* to the following:

```
    "start": "set PORT=60001 && react-scripts start",
```

I now have a requirement to run this in a Docker container using the same port. In my Dockerfile I have these two stages:

```
FROM node:alpine as build
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN rm -f .npmrc

FROM build as build-dev
COPY ./public/ /app/public
COPY ./src/ /app/src
EXPOSE 60001
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Notice I'm exposing the port on the container that I expect the npm dev server to bind to.

I build the image as you'd expect, targeting the `build-dev` Docker stage above.

```
docker build --target build-dev -t my-app:local
```

I then run the container like this:

```
docker run -it -p 60001:60001 my-app:local
```

The intention is to bind my local port 60001 to the same port on the container when I expect my dev app  build to be running.

When I do this I see confirmation that npm is running the correct script and that the app has compiled. However, browsing to http://localhost:60001/ gives me nothing. Just an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, as if there's nothing there.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas? I'd hoped I might be able to get some insight from the container logs, but when I run `docker logs` for this container I just see the react scripts output confirming my app compiled.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **docker-compose** adding this one line solved the problem for me...

The line is `stdin_open: true`.

Here is a basic example of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test-app:
    stdin_open: true
    container_name: test-app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Example `Dockerfile` for reference:

```yaml
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

For more information on this I would checkout the github issue for `create-react-app`

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688)

---

Good luck! This drove me nuts for hours

PS Not sure how this will hold up in a production build

Comment: I've been stuck for hours today. Thank u.

Comment: In production you should not "yarn start", but you should build an optimized production build and serve it. Something like `react-scripts build && npx serve build`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the app bind with container localhost.

Try to debug

```
docker exec -it <container_id> ash
#then
curl localhost:60001
```

It should work on localhost.

To make it accessible from outside of container do the following.

```
# i think its window syantax
"start": "set PORT=60001 HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start",
```

or

```
"start": "PORT=60001 HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start",
```

**HOST:**

> By default, the development web server binds to all hostnames on the
>   device (localhost, LAN network address, etc.). You may use this
>   variable to specify a different host.

[advanced-configuration](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) [HOST option react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I get `ash: curl: not found`. I did still try your suggestion `"start": "set PORT=60001 HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start",` which crashed the container, but also `"start": "set PORT=60001 HOST=0.0.0.0 && react-scripts start",` which claimed to be running the dev server but still no site on localhost. I also tried adding `ENV HOST=0.0.0.0` to my Dockerfile before the `EXPOSE` line and using the original `start` script, but still same problem.

Comment: Apk add - - no-cache curl amd try

Comment: Also it would be great if provid link to github repo so I can try

Comment: Cheers, will try when I get a chance. Unfortunately currently on a private repo. If I get a chance I'll try to get a demo up somewhere...