# Docker container exited abruptly during react-scripts start

Tags: reactjs

I want to run a simple React application inside Docker. It runs well outside but when I try to run it from docker, I get the following errors and at the moment I have no clue.

```
custportal_1         | yarn run v1.15.2
custportal_1         | $ react-scripts start
custportal_1         | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.24.0.12/
custportal_1         | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
custportal_1         | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
custportal_1         | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
custportal_1         | Starting the development server...
custportal_1         | 
custportal_1         | Done in 2.61s.
custportal_1 exited with code 0
```

The application is created by create-react-app command. My Dockerfile configuration is

```
FROM node:11 as build-deps
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build
```

Again the application runs well outside but breaks when called inside Docker. In docker-compose I call the container with

```
command: bash -c "export PORT=8081 && yarn start"
```

** I have nginx reverse proxy running on the background.

Comment: What error are you seeing? I only see the command in the post

Comment: Some possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419110/unable-to-run-a-development-build-of-a-react-app-in-a-docker-container-using-nod

Comment: Some possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790440/docker-container-exiting-immediately-after-starting-when-using-npm-init-react-ap

Answer (score 1):

Adding `stdin_open: true` in docker-compose solves the problem. Took hand-full of hours to get this solution. Reference [github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3106)

Also I have noticed that react-script was calling the browser abruptly inside docker during start up. It's not necessary inside docker. Adding environment variable like `BROWSER=none` can omit this behaviour.

Happy coding..