# React js isn't running my app on localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs

hi all i used to work on `MERN` project for sometime but now my `react` app wont run on `localhost:3000`. So far i tried the following

1. Updated `node.js`/ reinstalled node.js
2. create new app using `npx create-react-app` but still `localhost:3000` isn't working

I checked if port is opened or not using `netstat -aon` but `localhost:3000` wasn't there. But `0.0.0.0:3000` is there. So my attempt to run `telnet 127.0.0.1 3000` was not successful.

Am using `windows 10` OS and latest version of nodejs

Comment: Kindly share the error returned.

Comment: No error. When i run it, my browser says localhost took too long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Are you sure you have valid proxy settings. Maybe you are running server side not client side?

Comment: Am sure. Even if i create a new empty app using npx create-react-app, it is the same. Both server and client run without error but not accessible.

Comment: That error implies that your server and client aren't communicating. This might have to do more with the resources on your machine. If machine is running other intensive processes, you might need to stop them first.

Comment: My machine is not running other intensive processes.

Answer (score 3):

create .env file at the root of your project and add this line:

```
PORT = 3000
```

Then npm start again

Answer (score 2):

Try the solution from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project).

In package.json edit next string from this

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to this

```
"start": "set PORT=3000 && react-scripts start"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution i did installed a package htt-proxy-middleware which actually bugged some files in react, still not sure.
but simply you can get back to work by deleting your package-lock.json and entering
`npm i`
to reinstall all the packages. It worked for me. I hope it will solve the problem for other developers too.

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating your react-scripts version if you use create-react-app

The error also occurs if you have an outdated version of react-scripts in your create-react-app project.

## if you use npm

npm install react-scripts@latest

## if you use yarn

yarn add react-scripts@latest