# EOF the only output on localhost:3000 after launching React JS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, windows, npm

The browser just outputs 'EOF' when I launch my react js app.

**Things I have tried so far:**

- I have updated react, node js.
- I have deleted node_modules and ran `npm i`
- I have tried creating a new project and the problem exists there as well.
- [React js isn't running my app on localhost:3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031192/react-js-isnt-running-my-app-on-localhost3000) tried this as well but did not work

I work on Windows 10 x64 and do you need any other config/code?
Thanks!

EDIT:
[the screenshot of the website output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGKEO.png)

EDIT: **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the source view / console?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new. Can you please explain where do I look at?

Comment: Ctrl+U to look at the source, F12 to open the dev tools.

Comment: nope, nothing there

Comment: Right, so we need more info. How did you create the react app, how are you trying to run it?

Comment: created the react app on vs code's terminal through npm in v14.16.0 using the standard command and I am running it using `npm start`

Comment: I think @Chris G mean that , Did you create the app with `create-react-app` cli ?

Comment: When you type `npm start`, are you getting the window that says "Starting development server"? Does the browser open a new tab to localhost:3000? What *exactly* do you see in the source view? Because if you see EOF in the main browser window, the source can't be empty. Also, is there really nothing in the console? Like nothing at all?

Comment: It does say "Starting development server", opens a new tab to localhost:3000 and there is nothing in the source view, I will attach a screenshot to show the state of the app