# How do I change localhost:3000 to "custom.domain.dev" for a React app built with create-react-app for CORS

Tags: reactjs, localhost, create-react-app

I am running into a CORS issue when trying to have my React app send post requests to an api endpoint while using localhost:3000.

How do I configure my app to use `custom.domain.dev` instead of localhost:3000?

I have `/etc/hosts` setup to to include `127.0.0.1    custom.domain.dev` as well as my .env file to include `HOST=custom.domain.dev`.

As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin) stackoverflow question,

> Chrome does not support localhost for CORS requests (a bug opened in 2010, marked WontFix in 2014).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two parts of the question -

**Regarding the CORS flag on local host**

CORS flag is raised by the Browser when there is a request from a domain/port to an entire new domain/port. If you are doing this for testing, you can disable this security flag in chrome by adding the --disable-web-security flag. Just create a shortcut of chrome to desktop > Right click > Properties >In shortcut tab - Target > Append --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\tmpChromeSession" to target. This will disable the CORS check.

In real cases, if you have access/control on the api server, what you should be doing is to enable CORS on server by adding necessary response headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to the response. If you do not have access, one option will be to route the request through a CORS proxy.

**Change port**

You can change the running port of the react app on the `package.json` [See this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project). If you run the app on your machine, you are stuck with localhost.