# CORS Blocking React App from getting values

Tags: reactjs, slim

So I have an app with Slim PHP framework and I am allowing a certain port, however, the header been sent is from localhost:3002, but NPM is starting in port 3000...weird?

API:

```
return $response->withJson($remappedData)
    ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000'
```

obviously because of that, my get rquest fails.  any ideas?

if i npm start -p 3002, it sort of reverts back to 3000

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view mint-apt-finder in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://'interal-ip':3000
```

Comment: what happens if you run the react app on port 3002  (npm start -p 3002)

Comment: @TadeoHepperle I updated my qustions.   it sort of reverts back to port 3000

Comment: what react compiler are you using? Next.js? Parcel? The standard one?

Comment: @TadeoHepperle the standard one.

Comment: If it is about project from create-react-app, please see this right way to start from different port -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848/3849555