# Can I redirect request to port 80 to port 443 in a React-App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Im building a React-app and currently want to redirect requests to the port 80 (via http://...) to the port 443 (respond as https://...). I handle de url change on my app constructor (checking window.location), but actually, my problem is about docker I think. On my docker-compose i have something like:

```
.... (image of reactapp)
ports:
  - "443:443"
  - "80:443"
....
```

So, my react app is just listen to port 443, some suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848/952310

Comment: I currently create my app indicating in the .env file the 443 port, i have run my app correctly but, when some request arrive to the port 80, the server does not respond (doing request out of the container)

Comment: Sounds like you need to look for docker container port mapping: https://runnable.com/docker/binding-docker-ports