# React app is showing blank page on localhost:3000 but working on localhost:3001

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

I downloaded a repo of a react app from github and installed all the necessary dependencies. Then in ran `npm start` which started the dev server on `localhost:3000`. While on this port the app is showing a blank page but if I run the dev server on a different port like `localhost:3001`, it works fine but I need it to run on `localhost:3000`.

> I searched for the solution on google and tried every single solution possible to fix this issue, but nothing is solving it.

How do I make my app work on `localhost:3000` rather than other ports?

Comment: Is there a port explicitly specified in package.json? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848

Comment: @kiner_shah I tried this solution but it still doesn't fix my problem, I don't want to change  port, I want my app to work on `localhost:3000`

Comment: Is something else running on port 3000?

Comment: @kiner_shah I intentionally run an app on `localhost:3000` so that my starts on `3001`, because I didn't know the solution you provided. My requirement is not to open this app on another port, I want this app to run on `3000`. Thanks though.

Comment: No two apps can run on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the explicit PORT argument from your scripts in  package.json

looks something like this

```
"start": "PORT=3001 react-scripts start"
```

or if there's an env file containing the port Variable?

remove it.

make sure you are not running multiple react apps, that will make your app use another port if the default port is busy.

leme know if it fixies the issue if not .. please link to the repo you are using.

Comment: I want my app to work on port `3000` not to open on a different port.

Comment: The problem you are having is genrally caused by the things mentioned above.  Make sure the port is not busy, and there are no explicit port arguments passed this usually solves the issue.. if not please link the repo you are using.

Comment: `https://github.com/ssaimur/fbcClone-front.git` this is my repo, try cloning this repo and get the front page from this app on port `3000`. If you open this app on port `3001` you can't be able to login or register.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/register .. for me the app started in localhost 3000 it only means that you had another app running on the default port ie 3000. You can only host one app on a port at a time (doesn't matter if it's an express angular or react app). If you are not running multiple apps try restarting your system. The port might not have been closed properly . if none of this works make sure you havn't set any Port variables using the terminal . side note : it's a nice looking app and sorry about creating a test account .. you can delete it