# React.js : How to start a react application on a different port

Tags: reactjs, localhost, port, create-react-app

I just have started learning **React.js** and made two projects using **Create React App**.

Now if I want to start both projects at the same time, I can't because both start on port **3000** by default.

Is there any way I can change the default port of one of them to something else like http://localhost:3001 and run them simultaneously?

*Note: I'm a Windows user*

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848/14015126) might be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify `start` command from `scripts` section of `package.json`.

```
"start": “set PORT=3005 && react-scripts start"
```

There are couple of other ways also.
Refer this link
https://tech.amikelive.com/node-830/reactjs-changing-default-port-3000-in-create-react-app/

PS:
You can specify the port number which you want.

Comment: Just landed here. For all Mac/linux users: instead of `set PORT=3005` do `export PORT=3005`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .env file in the root of your project, and then put this in it:

```
PORT=3001
```

Then you don't have to worry about Windows vs Mac/Linux differences.