# Let the git bash choose the next available port automatically (Windows)

Tags: terminal, create-react-app, git-bash

I'm developing in React and my `package.json` has the following code:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
},
```

I was using Git Bash as a VS Code's embedded terminal. When I'm running multiple projects, I simply open multiple VS Code windows with their own terminal and simply run `npm start` and they work. If any project is running on Port 3000 the bash automatically suggests/choose the next available port for me.

But recently I'm seeing some performance issues using the embedded terminal from VS Code.

Hence I decided to use standalone Git Bash to run individual projects in watch mode. I opened up the first project and run, then I opened up another Git Bash on another project, but the `npm start` command simply is exiting with

> Something is already running on port 3000.

I've tried many solutions like `npm start --port=3001` and `npm start -- --port=3001` from my Git Bash, but nothing worked.

How can I let my Git Bash on Windows behave as they behaved in VS Code's embedded terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You may find many solutions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770848/1743124

But one of the out-of-the-box solutions that worked for me in Windows, is...
...using **Windows PowerShell**

[image: Windows PowerShell to choose the next available port]

Open Windows PowerShell on the next projects and write `npm start`
The terminal will inform you that the port is been used, and with a prompt, it can run on the next available port.

PS: On Windows 11, you can have an "Open PowerShell window here" context menu item.