# How can I run multiple React projects simultaneously on different ports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to run many project in 3000 port at the same time.

How can I change react port for run multiple react project at the same time. Any solution for this problem?

Show this message:
**Something is already running on port 3000.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify a port to run a create-react-app based project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project)

Comment: Even easier than the link above suggest would be just: `PORT=3006 npm start` instead of `npm start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the "scripts" section in your package.json, in the "start" also set the environment variable PORT with a value different than 3000:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3500 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If React app created with Vite, add port to server block in `vite.config.js`.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],

  server: {
    // change to desired port
    port: 3000
  }
})
```