# Is it Possible to see my wesbite im working on in my Iphone?

Tags: responsive-design

I am wondering if i can see my WIP website on my Iphone without publishing it. Is there any app or anything so i can see it on my phone. I know you can for example resize you browser to  act likte a phone and with google you can use the tools to get the screen to be as a phone, but its not the same as having to see the whole thing on your phone, that way you can see the whole thing responsive and can work easier from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access a website running on localhost from iPhone browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/how-do-you-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-iphone-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be setting up a development environment and publish to that instance.  In many cases you'll find developers with sub-domains like dev.domain.com for purposes just like this.  Hope this helps...