# WordPress in lamp server i cant access it from wlan after port forwarding

Tags: tcp, localhost, apache2, web-hosting, ngrok

I'm trying to create a website, but when I port it forward using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), I am not able to access it.

I am using a lamp server in Linux. I tried to access the website through my phone, but it shows this error and when I search using ngrok url it automatically changes the localhost in my phone browser.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what command you type to launch ngrok to share your site outside?

Comment: I used the command "ngrok http 80" this command @pat. ANDRIA

Comment: Looks like you didn't install a webserver *on your phone* (as you're connecting to `localhost`). Note: localhost always refers to *the host that the browser is on*. Most likely you're not intending to install a webserver on your phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you access a website running on localhost from iPhone browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/how-do-you-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-iphone-browser)

Comment: I have port forwarded my website in my pc using ngrok and when i use the ngrok port forwarded url in my mobile browser it gets replaced to localhost

Comment: I am not hosting my website from my phone i am using a linux pc to host my website using ngrok so i don't want to install a webserver in my phone

Answer (score 0):

Locally, I can access one of my local website using `http://localhost`.
Now, I would like to share this website on the internet.

(By the way, this is not the way to deploy your site, only to share temporarily).

Using the command line,  I use `ngrok` like this:

```sh
patou@pa-linux:~$ ./ngrok-stable-linux-amd64/ngrok http 80
```

This results in a display like the following:

[image]

What I see, from the image you uploaded, is that you try to access your website using `http://localhost` from the internet.

You do not access you site from outside as `localhost` but as the random name provided by `ngrok`. Here it is `http://19cfca2ea9c5.ngrok.io`. It will work better