# getting issues while trying to call api (local host) from real ios device(Mac OS)

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments, deep-linking

first, I run the nodeJs server on localhost
then I tried to call API's from my real ios device, but I’m getting issues while connecting with local host

[image]

everything in working fine in case of android device and emulator

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the backend on `0.0.0.0` if you want to test from a different device, but in the same network. The 0.0.0.0 will listen on all network interfaces where localhost might only listen to your local loopback net device.

You should also point to your network address where the backend is running from your iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/how-do-you-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-iphone-browser) helpful.
That localhost URL would make the iPhone try to reach out to itself, you need to set that variable to an IP or URL that the iPhone can actually reach out to. You may find it helpful to use a tunnelling service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which will make an external URL that your server's localhost can be reached at.