# How to test localhost site on cell phone?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My scenario is like, I want to test my website on cell phone, which is located on my localhost. 
It is WordPress site.

My website is not deployed yet on any server. so, Is there anyway to test my localhost site on cell phone?

The question you were referring me it's having a different kind of solution, when compare to my question. because i didn't modified http.config file. i didn't modified my wamp settings.
can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Take the IP address of your computer and get your phone on the same network and type `http://yourip`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up WAMP to run on LAN, including mobile access, iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695785/setting-up-wamp-to-run-on-lan-including-mobile-access-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check your localhost IP and you will run it on your phone.
But your system and cell phone will be connected with internet.

Comment: Is it necessary to both the system having same LAN connection?